# How to find permission level for specific user using visual studio?

Tags: permissions, spuser

How to find permission level for specific user in site collection and subsite using visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found Solution..

```
public static string FindPermissionLevelForUser(string loginname, string strSite)

    {
        string strValue = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strSite))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        string spreturnUser = string.Empty;

                        try
                        {
                            SPUser user = web.Users[loginname];
                            SPRoleAssignment currentUserRole = web.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(user);


                            foreach (SPRoleDefinition role in currentUserRole.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                            {
                                strValue += role.Name + ", ";
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            //if user in group
                            SPGroupCollection groupColl = web.Groups;

                            foreach (SPGroup group in groupColl)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    SPUser user = group.Users[loginname];
                                    SPRoleAssignment currentUserRole = web.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(group);

                                    foreach (SPRoleDefinition role in currentUserRole.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                                    {
                                        strValue += role.Name + ", ";
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return string.Empty;

        }
        return strValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Getting Permission levels for a site](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/06e20e89-d95f-45a2-b3cd-7fd011ed8738/?Getting%20the%20permission%20levels%20from%20SharePoint%202010%20using%20C)

[Adding or Removing Permissions for a user or group](http://rmanimaran.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/programatically-adding-and-removing-permission-to-a-group-in-sharepoint-list/)

[Custom permission levels](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/how-to-create-a-custom-permission-level-in-sharepoint-2010/)

If you go through above links, I am pretty sure you will figure out code you need for what you're trying to do.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the permissions for current user using this code

```
SPBasePermissions bp = 
SPContext.Current.Web.GetUserEffectivePermissions
    (SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Already answered for the SharePoint server side objects. Just in case if you wish to find out for client side code for getting permission level of the group please refer the following link. It is similar to the server side code but you can control when to put the code into the wire.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24087.how-to-get-the-permission-levels-associated-with-sharepoint-user-groups-using-client-object-model-in-netc.aspx

Comment: This answer needs more details, it is too dependent on the link (if the link breaks it will be of no help in the future)