# Issues with SPPrincipals on SP2013

Tags: spuser, spprincipal

I'm having some troubles with getting SPPrincipals, was hoping if anybody would point me to the right direction.

Here is the scoop:
I need to grant permissions to SPItem.
I get SPUser:

```
SPUser user = web.AllUsers.GetByID    // {i:0#.w|domain\ad_name}
```

Check what current permissions for the user:

```
SPRoleAssignment currentUserRole = item.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(user);
```

Getting exception:

> {"Can not find the principal with id: 38."}  // 38 is correct site
>   user id

If I'm trying to resolve SPPrincipal:

```
SPPrincipalInfo pi = SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal(webApp, null, user.LoginName, SPPrincipalType.All, SPPrincipalSource.All, false);
```

Getting **not null SPPrincipalInfo** object but with **PrincipleId = -1**, not sure what it means.

Tried to google on "Can not find the principal with id:", could not find much.
How come it correctly resolves site user id but does not recognize it as SPPrincipal id?

Answer (score 4):

`GetAssignmentByPrincipal` throwing `ArgumentException "Can not find the principal with id: {0}"` says `SPRoleAssignmentCollection` doesn't contain a `SPRoleAssignment` for that principal. Basically, it's just a search from Principal-to-Roles hashtable, and it fails.

Something like `foreach (var ra in item.RoleAssignments){Console.WriteLine(ra.Member.ID)}` will list all suitable IDs that won't make it throw an exception.

Maybe you should check `SPListItem.DoesUserHavePermissions` and `SPListItem.GetUserEffectivePermissions` methods

Comment: Thanks Aziz! 
Does it mean just catch it and ignore? Will try next week

Comment: Sure, my pleasure. Please see the answer updated.

Comment: Indeed, trapping the exception and ignoring it does the job. I was puzzled by the fact of exception, was not sure how to deal with it. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following code [example](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/54721/9345), when used, you can pass a site and login id, and get respective permissions, whether as a user or member in a group in the respective site.

```
public static string FindPermissionLevelForUser(string loginname, string strSite)

    {
        string strValue = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strSite))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        string spreturnUser = string.Empty;

                        try
                        {
                            SPUser user = web.Users[loginname];
                            SPRoleAssignment currentUserRole = web.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(user);


                            foreach (SPRoleDefinition role in currentUserRole.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                            {
                                strValue += role.Name + ", ";
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            //if user in group
                            SPGroupCollection groupColl = web.Groups;

                            foreach (SPGroup group in groupColl)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    SPUser user = group.Users[loginname];
                                    SPRoleAssignment currentUserRole = web.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(group);

                                    foreach (SPRoleDefinition role in currentUserRole.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                                    {
                                        strValue += role.Name + ", ";
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return string.Empty;

        }
        return strValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [SPWeb.EnsureUser(loginName)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx) to make sure the user is known to the item's parent web.
This function will create a user reference / object in that `SPWeb` if the user is not already known for that specific `SPWeb` without granting actual permissions. 
The function return an `SPUser` object which you can then use to create an `SPRoleAssignment` with.