# Get level permission using user login name?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, development, permissions

I'm on SharePoint 2013 and I'm using C#. I'm working with the `ItemAdding` event receiver.
Using `SPItemEventProperties` I can get the user login name associated with the file I'm adding, with this kind of format: `i:0#.w|domain\\example` (`UserLoginName` property). 
I also have a `SPListItem` object and I want to check if the user has Full Control permission level on this item.
I can't find a working solution, could someone help me, please? 
I tried working with `SPBasePermissions` but `FullMask` seems not equivalent to Full Control.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to check if the current user has Full Control Permission

```
if (SPContext.Current.Web.AllRolesForCurrentUser.Contains(SPContext.Current.Web.RoleDefinitions["Full Control"]))
{
//do something
}
```

If it's not working try the below code:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strSite))
{
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{  
try
{
SPUser user = web.Users["current user"];
SPRoleAssignment currentUserRole = web.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(user);
foreach (SPRoleDefinition role in currentUserRole.RoleDefinitionBindings)
{
if (role.Name.ToString() == "Full Control")
{
 // has full control
}
}
}
 catch (Exception)
{
throw;
}
}
}
```

For more details check [How to find permission level for specific user using visual studio?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54691/how-to-find-permission-level-for-specific-user-using-visual-studio)